# TransactionSystemException when @Scheduled is used

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When I want to use @Scheduled, it throws org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
When I tried to use noRollbackFor=TransactionSystemException - it does not help either...
I even tried to use propagation=NEVER and then the code does not work,because it needs to be transactional. Iam getting those documents ok, but I cannot do blockDocument(document).
How to make it work?
Thank you in advance

```
    @Component
        public class ScheduleService {

            @Autowired
            private DocumentService documentService;


            @Scheduled(cron = "0 33 13 * * ?")
            public void blockPassedDocuments() {
                List<Document> passedDocuments = documentService.getAllPassedDocuments();
                if (passedDocuments != null) {
                    System.out.println("blocked docs "+ passedDocuments.size());
                    passedDocuments.forEach(document -> documentService.blockDocument(document));
                }
            }
        }

            @Service
            @Transactional
            public class DocumentService {
                @Autowired
                private DocumentRepository documentRepository;
                @Autowired
                private UserService userService;
                @Autowired
                private EmailService emailService;

                @Transactional(noRollbackFor = TransactionSystemException.class)
                public void blockDocument(Document document){
                    documentRepository.blockDocument(document);
                }

            // repository
            @Override
                public void blockDocument(Document document) {
                    DocumentState documentState = getDocumentState(3);
                    document.setDocumentState(documentState);

                    entityManager.merge(document);
                }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "document_state")
    public class DocumentState {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @NotBlank(message = "State is mandatory")
        @Size(min=1, max=60)
        @Column(length = 60)
        private String state;

        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentState", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Document> documents;

        public DocumentState(){

        }

@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 60, nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 15)
    @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "Description is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_state_id", nullable = false)
    private DocumentState documentState;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "resource_path", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String resourcePath;

    @Column(name = "upload_datetime", columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull(message = "UploadDateTime is mandatory")
    private Date uploadDatetime;


    @Column(name = "approval_end_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull(message = "Approval end time is mandatory")
    private Date approvalEndTime;


    @Column(name = "active_start_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull(message = "Active start time is mandatory")
    private Date activeStartTime;

    @Column(name = "active_end_time", columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull(message = "Active end time is mandatory")
    private Date activeEndTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UsersDocuments> documentsForUsers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

     public DocumentState getDocumentState() {
        return documentState;
    }
```

EDIT STACK:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:541) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.patrikmaryska.bc_prace.bc_prace.service.ScheduleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68ed607b.blockPassedDocuments(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Can you place the full stack? The actual problem seems to be swallowe somewhere

Comment: Also place the DocumentState entity mapping

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski added.

Comment: Thanks can you also add Document entity and the getDocumentState method

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski done

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@Transactional` annotation on `blockPassedDocuments` method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@Transactional` annotation on `ScheduleService` class.

Comment: It did not help :(